# Защита приложения от распаковки (СМС авторизация)

Tags: android, защита, sms, reverse-engineering

Прошу помощи.

В нашей компании есть мобильное приложении на Android.

Неделю назад мы заметили огромное количество смс с авторизацией на одинаковые номера.

Оказалось что кто то распаковал приложение, стащил логин и пароль и добавил запрос к нашему серверу в спам скрипт.

За неделю прошло 80000 смс, ранее при нормальном использовании было порядка 800 смс в день.

Каким образом можно защититься от такого нестандартного использования приложения?

Comment: Запустить баг-баунти программу, и фиксить найденные ресёрчерами дыры.